# React table, how to show blank column if object value does not match

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

How can I render blank data in specific column if value in object does not match

Data from API

```
 [
  {
    "parent": "parent1",
    "ouid": 1,
    "child1": "tom",
    "child2": "bob"
  },
  {
    "parent": "parent2",
    "ouid": 2,
    "child1": "smith",
    "child2": "steven"
  },
  {
    "parent": "parent3",
    "ouid": 1,
    "child1": "mack",
    "child2": "jack"
  }
]
```

Column mapping

```
const defaultColumns = [
  table.createDataColumn("parent", {
    id: "parent",
  }),
  table.createGroup({
    header: "ouid",
    columns: [
      table.createDataColumn("child1", {
        id: "child1",
      }),

      table.createDataColumn("child2", {
        id: "child2",
      }),
    ],
  }),
  table.createGroup({
    header: "ouid1",
    columns: [
      table.createDataColumn("child1", {
        id: "child1",
      }),

      table.createDataColumn("child2", {
        id: "child2",
      }),
    ],
  }),
];
```

Table Mapping

```
<table border={1}>
        <thead>
          {instance.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                <th key={header.id} colSpan={header.colSpan}>
                  {header.isPlaceholder ? null : header.renderHeader()}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {instance.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
            <tr key={row.id}>
              {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                <td key={cell.id}>{cell.renderCell()}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Output

[image: Output]

Expected Output

[image: Expected Output]

I want different column group to be rendered based on value of 'ouid' and it's child column will always be 'child1','child2'
rest all common column will be filled 'parent' in this case, new column group will be created for another 'ouid' value and so on..., do let me know if I need to alter data from api in a specific way to achieve this.

@tanstack react-table version - 8.0.0-beta.4 (I can't update to latest stable, but can downgrade to v7 if this is achievable by it)

`row.getVisibleCells` return

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's the return of `row.getVisibleCells()` look like?

Comment: edited question which shows return of `row.getVisibleCells()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).